# Get rid of Google Chromes text input character suggestions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, osx-lion

When user uses Google Chrome and hold a key in text input for some time, Chrome suggests him some special chars he can use. Is there any programatical way, how to get rid of this tool?

Thanks.

[image: chrome suggestion on text input]

Comment: I didn't see this before , however what about using the attribute : autocomplete="off"

Comment: What version of Chrome do you get this in? - Just curious.

Comment: As already mentioned, this is a OS X Lion feature. As far as I know you can only disable it for your whole system: execute `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` in Terminal (apparently requires restart).

Comment: using chrome 16.0.912.77. autocomplete="off" didnt help. On Mac OS X, Firefox and Opera dont show this behavior. Safari also shows this menu.

Comment: That's probably because Safari and Chrome use one kind of text editing widget, while Firefox and Opera use another.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of OS X Lion, not Chrome.

Comment: True, but not a answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

can be fixed with this command:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

but you have to reboot the system to make it take effect (which is kind of ridiculous).